# Pubnub: How to use different UUID for each channel joined

Tags: pubnub

Is it possible to set different UUID for each channel that you've joined?

e.g. The user simultaneously joined different channels.

```
pubnub.subscribe({
    channel: [mainChannel, broadcastChannel, controllerChannel]
});
```

- **NOTE THAT I've assigned the UUID on PUBNUB.INIT()**

The reason why I've wanted to do this is because:

- On user login my app assigns a static UUID for the account. But different user account has different UUID (eg. user1-channel2, user2-channel2).
- The app allows multiple users to use the same account. So basically all of them have the same UUID and this is okay for "mainChannel" & "broadcastChannel" but not for "controllerChannel" as they should have unique UUID for the channel so I can identify different users not different accounts.

Is this possible? If it is not, then is there an alternative solution for my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using state! http://www.pubnub.com/docs/javascript/api/reference.html#state

State is still bound to a single uuid, but you can create an object that encapsulates arbitrary info around it.  For example, in your case, you should create an object like:

{"mainChannel":"foo", "userChannel":"bar", "controlChannel":"baz"}

Shoot us an email at support@pubnub.com if this does not work for you, we can discuss alternatives still.

geremy